# NodeJS: Handling transactions with NoSQL databases?

Tags: node.js, database, transactions, promise, nosql

Consider a promise-chained chunk of code for example:

```
return Promise.resolve()
  .then(function () {
    return createSomeData(...);
  })
  .then(function () {
    return updateSomeData(...);
  })
  .then(function () {
    return deleteSomeData(...);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    return ohFishPerformRollbacks();
  })
  .then(function () {
    return Promise.reject('something failed somewhere');
  })
```

In the above code, let's say something went wrong in the function `updateSomeData(...)`. Then one would have to revert the create operation that was executed before this.

In another case, if something went wrong in the function `deleteSomeData(...)`, then one would want to revert the operations executed in `createSomeData(...)` and `updateSomeData(...)`. 
This would continue as long as all the blocks have some revert operations defined for themselves in case anything goes wrong.

Only if there was a way in either NodeJs or the database or somewhere in the middle, that would revert all the transactions happening under the same block of code.

**One way I can think of this to happen is by flagging all the rows in database with a `transactionId (ObjectID)` and a `wasTransactionSuccessful(boolean)`, so that CRUD operations could be clubbed together with their `transactionId`s, and in case something goes wrong, those transactions could be simply deleted from the database in the ending catch block.**

I read about rolling back transactions in https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/. But I want to see if it can be done in a more simpler fashion and in a generic manner for NoSQL databases to adapt.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this would satisfy your use case, but I hope it would.

```
    let indexArray = [1, 2, 3];
    let promiseArray = [];
    let sampleFunction = (index) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(resolve, 100, index);
        });
    }
    indexArray.map((element) => {
        promiseArray.push(sampleFunction(element));
    });
    Promise.all(promiseArray).then((data) => {
        // do whatever you want with the results
    }).catch((err) => {
        //Perform your entire rollback here
    });
```

```
async.waterfall([
    firstFunc,
    secondFunc
], function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
        // delete the entire thing
    }
});
```

Using the async library would give you a much elegant solution than going with chaining.

Comment: Using async or promise.all is useful in cases where CRUD operations need to be performed simultaneously. I am talking about chaining here because imagine saving something to database, and then using the saved data to create/update/delete something else.

Comment: @kamal0808 Async.waterfall runs the array of functions in series, passing results to next function in the array.
Ref: https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#waterfall